What is the "do no harm" clause in the hippocratic oath?
In my old notes I have the following written down as the wording for the Hippocratic oath (specifically the 'do no harm' clause):

ⲱⲥ ⲉⲡⲓ ⲛⲟⲥⲱⲛ ⲉⲝⲓⲥ ⲉⲭⲏ ⲇⲩⲟ· ⲏ ⲃⲟⲏⲑⲉⲓⲛ· ⲏ ⲙⲏ ⲃⲗⲁⲡⲧⲉⲓⲛ·
"When it comes to diseases let there be a two-fold custom: either help, or [at least] do no harm."

However I can't hunt down the source on the internet. And on top of that, it seems that there are different versions of the oath.
So my question is this: what is the wording of the original? And likewise: what is the manuscript that contains it?

Which version are you looking for, specifically? The first known mention of the oath is found in Scribonius Largus, Compositiones, 1st century AD ("Hippocrates, conditor nostrae professionis, initia di sciplinae ab iureiurando tradidit, in quo sanctum est, ne praegnati quidem medicamentum, quo conceptum excutitur, aut detur aut demonstretur a quoquam medico, longe praeformans animos discentium ad humanitatem.") The first known textual evidence comes from a papyrus of the 3rd century AD, which (to my limited knowledge) does not contain the "do no harm" clause.

Yeah, the manuscript trail might be more difficult to hunt down.  And I'm already seeing variation. The post below has the same thoughts that are in my notes, but the wording is different.

The statement occurs in Epidemics I in the Hippocratic Corpus as (both texts are from Perseus Digital Library)

χΙ. ὅσα διὰ κινδύνων, πεπασμοὺς τῶν ἀπιόντων πάντας πάντοθεν
ἐπικαίρους ἢ καλὰς καὶ κρισίμους ἀποστάσιας σκοπεῖσθαι. πεπασμοὶ
ταχυτῆτα κρίσιος καὶ ἀσφάλειαν ὑγιείης σημαί νουσιν, ὠμὰ δὲ καὶ ἄπεπτα
καὶ ἐς κακὰς ἀποστάσιας τρεπόμενα ἀκρισίας ἢ πόνους ἢ χρόνους ἢ
θανάτους ἢ τῶν αὐτῶν ὑποστροφάς. ὅ τι δὲ τούτων ἔσται μάλιστα,
σκεπτέον ἐξ ἄλλων. λέγειν τὰ προγενόμενα, γινώσκειν τὰ παρεόντα,
προλέγειν τὰ ἐσόμενα: μελετᾶν ταῦτα. ἀσκεῖν περὶ τὰ νοσήματα δύο,
ὠφελεῖν ἢ μὴ βλάπτειν. ἡ τέχνη διὰ τριῶν, τὸ νόσημα καὶ ὁ νοσέων καὶ ὁ
ἰητρός: ὁ ἰητρὸς ὑπηρέτης τῆς τέχνης: ὑπεναντιοῦσθαι τῷ νοσήματι τὸν
νοσέοντα μετὰ τοῦ ἰητροῦ.

XI. In all dangerous cases you should be on the watch for all favourable coctions of the evacuations from all parts, or for fair and critical abscessions. Coctions signify nearness of crisis and sure recovery

[] of health, but crude and unconcocted evacuations, which change into
bad abscessions, denote absence of crisis, pain, prolonged illness,
death, or a return of the same symptoms. But it is by a consideration
of other signs that one must decide which of these results will be
most likely. Declare the past, diagnose the present, foretell the
future ; practise these acts. As to diseases, make a habit of two
things--to help, or at least to do no harm. The art has three
factors, the disease, the patient, the physician. The physician is the
servant of the art. The patient must co-operate with the physician in
combating the disease.


Excellent. Thanks!

Glad to be of help.
